# About the real roots of $x^{2n+1}\pm x +1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How can I find the solutions of the following equations or at least show that there is a unique real solution? $$\text{ 1) }x^{2n+1}+ x +1 = 0$$ $$\text{ 2) } x^{2n+1}-x +1 = 0.$$ I've worked out a factorization of $x^{2n+1} \pm 1$, but it doesn't seem to help.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You probably can't get a good closed form for the roots of this polynomial.

Comment: You can definitely show that there is only one real solution to the first equation easily - the function is clearly strictly increasing.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Are you getting at the fact that the function is injective, that it has at least one zero because of the intermediate value theorem, and hence that zero must be unique?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What about the second one?

Comment: If $n \geq 1$ is an integer, then the first equation $x^{2n+1} + x + 1 = 0$ has exactly one real solution.

Since that there is at least one real number $x$ such that $x^{2n+1} + x + 1 = 0$ is obvious, I claim that there is at most one such $x$. If $x_{1} < x_{2}$ are two such, then
$$x_{1}^{2n+1} + x_{1} + 1 = x_{2}^{2n+1} + x_{2} + 1,$$
$$x_{1}^{2n+1} + x_{1} = x_{2}^{2n+1} + x_{2},$$
$$x_{1}^{2n+1} - x_{2}^{2n+1} = x_{2} - x_{1}.$$
But 
$x_{1}^{2n+1} - x_{2}^{2n+1} < 0$
and
$x_{2} - x_{1} > 0.$

Comment: For $n=0$ the second statement is false: there is no real (or complex) solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Since $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{2n+1}+x+1) = x^{2n}+1 > 0$, the function is increasing on $\mathbb{R}$. Since the limits at $\pm\infty$ are $\pm\infty$, there is at least, and exactly, one real root. Such a root belongs to the interval $(-1,0)$ since $f(-1)<0$ while $f(0)>0$.

**2)** For $n>0$, the function $g(x)=x^{2n+1}-x$ has three real roots, $\{-1,0,1\}$, and the minimum of such a function on the interval $[0,1]$ occurs in the point $x_0$ for which $(2n+1) x_0^{2n} = 1$, hence $x_0^{2n+1}=\frac{x_0}{2n+1}$ and $|g(x_0)|\leq\frac{2n}{2n+1}$. This gives that for any $\alpha>\frac{2n}{2n+1}$, $g(x)+\alpha$ has only one real root $\xi_n<-1$.

Comment: In the second equation, could you explicitly deal with the case $n=0$ that has no solution? You probably should explicitly show that the other values of $n$ do have at least one real solution, since that is easy to show.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: $n>0$ was more or less implicit since I wrote "$g(x)$ has *three* real roots", anyway I made it clear now.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, could you clarify what comes after "hence"?

Comment: @user62029: the first step is just a multiplication by $x_0$, followed by the evaluation of $g(x)$ in $x_0$.